# grant role to schema

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, role, sql-grant

```
GRANT ROLE_BLAH_GENERAL TO BLAH_USER
```

I encountered this error

```
ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'ROLE_BLAH_GENERAL'
```

Then I reformed the query to

```
GRANT ROLE_BLAH_GENERAL TO BLAH_USER WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

I then encountered

```
ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'ROLE_BLAH_GENERAL'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Looks like the User you logged in as was not granted this role with ADMIN option

Answer (score 4):

The user that issues the `GRANT` needs to have been granted the role `WITH ADMIN OPTION`.  Otherwise, the user doesn't have permission to grant the role to others.

If you want user `FOO`, for example, to be able to grant the `ROLE_BLAH_GENERAL` role to other users, the DBA would need to

```
GRANT role_blah_general
   TO foo
 WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Once that is done, `FOO` should be able to grant the role to other users

```
GRANT role_blah_general
   TO blah_user
```

Of course, you may prefer that the DBA that granted `ROLE_BLAH_GENERAL` to `FOO` be the one to grant the role to `BLAH_USER` so that `FOO` doesn't need the role `WITH GRANT OPTION`.